# Cannot redeclare NEWtimezone() (previously declared

Tags: php

It is a function of time zone conversion. If it is used in a cycle - an error: Can not redeclare NEWtimezone () (previously declared...

```
    function NEWtimezone($time,$defaultzone,$newzone)
    {
    $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($defaultzone));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($newzone));
    $result=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
    return $result;
    }

$newzone="Europe/Moscow";
$defaultzone = "+1000";
$time = "2016-09-29 07:27:00.966";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Can not redeclare function NEWtimezone() ....` error means that function `NEWtimezone()` already defined but your code tries to define it once again.

Make sure that function definition is placed outside the loop.